# How can I add a watchkit settings bundle

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am programming a stand alone watch app and am trying to implement a settings menu for my app (in the settings app). I read about watchkit settings bundle but can't find any new implementation or documentation. How am I adding these settings options nowadays?